# How to assign non-string value to a variable

Tags: python, ssl, openssl

I have this assignment:

context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1

taken from ssl python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3). Since the value after the assignemnt, can take different values:

```
ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
```

I thought of adding all the values in an array to make my code more readable. So I did the following:

```
noTLS = ['ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2','ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3','ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1','ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1']
```

Then:

```
context.options |= noTLS[3]
```

But I got an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'Options' and 'str'
```

Is there any way where I can put these non-string values in one place and call them by reference like an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean this:

```
noTLS = [ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2, ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3, ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1, ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1]
```

why did you convert them to `str` anyway?

I guess this code

```
context.options |= noTLS[3]
```

will work then just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting strings in your `noTLS` list, you can put in the actual values.

```
noTLS = [ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2, ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3, ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1, ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1]
```

Then

```
context.options |= noTLS[3]
```

should work.